# I am trying to set up django channels for a chat feature in my web app but i am getting DLL import error

Tags: python, django, cryptography, channel, ddl

File "C:\Users\user.virtualenvs\cinemahub-_4auLGIo\lib\site-packages\cryptography\exceptions.py", line 9, in 
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import exceptions as rust_exceptions
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: The specified procedure could not be found.

I uninstalled channels 3.0.5 and run python manage.py, the error disappeared. but the Asgi server wasnt showing on terminal. I installed channels 4.0.0 and Daphne but daphne causes the same error however when i remove daphne, the error disappears. I want the asgi server to show on the terminal.
I aslo installed and uninstalled cryptography numerous times yet error still appears

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install channels
pip install asgi_redis
pip install daphne
```

Comment: I just installed them with pip but am stilll getting    from cryptography.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\cinemahub-_4auLGIo\lib\site-packages\cryptography\exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import exceptions as rust_exceptions
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: The specified procedure could not be found.    when i add daphne to list of installed apps in settings. only daphne is causing this error when i add to list of installed apps

Comment: I was finally able to do it, i deleted the entire environment, created a new one and installed all the packages all over, and its working now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If adding **daphne** to **INSTALLED_APPS** causing this error, then make sure you add daphne to the top of INSTALLED_APPS as instructed by [channels official docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

> In order to solve such issues, make sure daphne is at the top of your
> INSTALLED_APPS or remove the offending app altogether.